# Is File.ReadAllLines thread safe?

Tags: asp.net, file-io, thread-safety

Do reading a text file inside asp.net multi threading environment thread safe ?

I mean reading text file like below

```
File.ReadAllLines(
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"textFiles\generic_anchors.txt")
).ToArray();
```

asp.net 4.5

Can above reading cause any exception ?

Comment: I'm not sure about thread-safety, but it can certainly throw an exception in general: See *Exceptions* section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx

Comment: Depends. Are any of the other threads *modifying* the same file? Or reading it via other means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and no.

If there is some code writing to the file, you need to synchronise all access to the file.

However, if you are only reading the file and it never changes while the site is running, then it's not a problem. Several threads can read the same file at the same time.

Side note: The `ToArray` call at the end is just a waste. The method already returns an array.

Comment: "Several threads can read the same file at the same time" - providing they're using this (or similar methods). If any thread is reading the file having explicitly opened the file with an overload that accepts a `FileShare` option and not specified `FileShare.Read` then that's no longer true.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Good point. By reading the file I meant that it would be accessed using a mode that was appropriate for that, thanks for clarifying further.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN on the [File class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3saad2h5.aspx)

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

Of course the exception problem is another game. If some other process get an exclusive lock on the file that you are trying to read the exception is guaranteed to happen

Comment: That is the standard text for all classes that doesn't do anything special for thread safety. Even if the method in itself is thread safe, the underlying resource may not be.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two different questions.

Thread-safety is concerned with eliminating race conditions (corruption, inconsistent results, deadlocks, etc.) when the same method(s) are called simultaneously via multiple threads. In the .NET BCL, I can't think of any `static` methods that *aren't* thread safe. That's not magical, however - if you were to create your own `static` method, you need to ensure it's thread safety.

So, the answer to your first question (from the title "Is File.ReadAllLines thread safe?"), is yes. Since `File.ReadAllLines` is a static method in the BCL, it is thread safe.

Your *second* question, however, is "Can above reading cause any exception[s]?". That has little to do with thread safety. A thread safe method can throw exceptions without sacrificing it's correctness. As [MSDN shows for `File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx), the list of possible exceptions is:

- ArgumentException
- ArgumentNullException
- PathTooLongException
- DirectoryNotFoundException
- IOException
- UnauthorizedAccessException
- FileNotFoundException
- NotSupportedException
- SecurityException

None of these exceptions have anything to do with thread-safety, and in fact are the same set of exceptions documented for the *non thread-safe* [`FileStream` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyhc0kft.aspx).